# ReferenceError: 'pictures' is not defined. Using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, referenceerror

Searched all over the place but can't get it running. I'm new here, so kinda hard for me also to search or fix the right thing.. Trying to fetch data from the database, but the pictures variable is not defined it says, I got it running before, maybe just a type error of something like that, but I tried already lots of things and i'm running out of time for my school project. This is my code:

index.ejs:

```
<main>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Formula 1, see it, feel it!</h1></br>
        <p>Welkom! Op deze site vind u de meest mooie foto's van de Formule 1.</p>
    </div>
</main>

<div class="jumbotron">

       <% if(pictures.length){ %>     
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Titel</th>
        <th>Locatie</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Waardering</th>

    </tr>
        <% } %>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>

        <td><%= pictures[i].titel %></td>
        <td><%= pictures[i].locatie %></td>
        <td><%= pictures[i].datum %></td>
        <td><%= pictures[i].naam %></td>
        <td><%= pictures[i].waardering %></td>
        <% } %>
    </tr>                   
</table>    

</div>

<footer>
    <% include ../partials/footer %>
</footer>
```

index.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM pictures', function(err, results) {
            res.locals.pictures = results;
            console.log(results);
            res.render('../views/pages/index');
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    mongo = require('mongodb'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    myConnection = require('express-myconnection');

var db = mongoose.connection;

var dbOptions = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'fcdeen_user',
    password: 'wEvGT9ctm8KUxdTD',
    database: 'fcdeen'
};

var indexRoutes = require('./routes/index'),    
    loginRoutes = require('./routes/login'),
    uploadRoutes = require('./routes/upload');

var app = express();

//Use session
app.use(session({
  secret: "Its_A_veRy_DarK_SecreT",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Voeg de bodyparser middleware aan de app toe (POST requests)
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Voeg connectie middleware toe aan app
app.use(myConnection(mysql, dbOptions, 'single'));

// index page 
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});

// index page 
app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});

// upload page 
app.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/upload');
});

// login page 
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/login');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Launch at port 8080');
```

And this is the error:

```
ReferenceError: C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\views\pages\index.ejs:21
   19| <div class="jumbotron">
   20|   
>> 21|   <% if(pictures.length){ %>     
   22| <table>
   23| <tr>
   24| <th>Titel</th>

pictures is not defined
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:242:14), <anonymous>:33:292)
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:242:14), <anonymous>:35:68)
   at C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:255:15
   at Object.exports.render (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:293:13)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:323:20)
   at View.render (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
   at EventEmitter.render (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
   at C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\app.js:61:6
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at next (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express-myconnection\lib\express-myconnection.js:123:9
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at trim_prefix (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
   at C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (C:\School\SSS 2015\testen\node-ejs-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you using a mysql database? could you specify the database and the driver you are using ?

Comment: Yes i'm using phpmyadmin, not sure what you mean with driver?

Comment: don't worry about the drive, I have already seen that you are using the `mysql` module. Could you please show us the output for `console.log(results);`. But please, modify it this way `console.log("Results: ", results.length);`

Comment: Can't see the output because its still giving that error. It shows only the error log

Comment: That is not possible. Your are showing the results before rendering the view. So you have to see something before the trace error generated rendering the view. If you change the code line that I told you, you should see something like `Results: ` and just after the stack trace.

Comment: Should I see it in my prompt or terminal? There I just see the error, which I posted above

Comment: You should see it in your terminal, where the node server is running. Could you please comment the `res.render` line. If we leave the `console.log()` alone we may see some information that we are not seeing due to the error.

Comment: Did exactly as you told, but still I don't get any data through the console in my terminal

Comment: ok, are you sure that your function is executing ? To be sure, add a simple `console.log()` in the first line. If you see a message in your terminal, you are in, else you are not executing that method. Have you sure that you url is `localhost:8080` ? If the url is something like  `localhost:8080/index` or  `localhost:8080/home` you will render the view without retrieving the data from the database. Be sure that you router is properly working.

Comment: Then I suppose the function is not being executed, because my login and upload routes are working and when I'm trying to use the index (8080/index, 8080/home or 8080/) I'm getting that error message on that page only. But I find it so strange because it worked before this way somehow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is the solution for your issue

```
// Don't separate the routes. If you are setting your routes in this file, try keep every route at the same file.

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM pictures', function(err, results) {
            res.locals.pictures = results;
            console.log(results);
            res.render('pages/index', {pictures : results});
        });
    });
});

// index page 
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});

// index page 
app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});
```

You have to see errors when you enter `/home` or `/index` but shouldn't have problem with `/`.

If you are trying that these three routes executes the same you could try this:

```
app.get('/', renderPageIndex)

// index page 
app.get('/home', renderPageIndex)

// index page 
app.get('/index', renderPageIndex )

function renderPageIndexfunction(req, res) {
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM pictures', function(err, results) {
            res.locals.pictures = results;
            console.log(results);
            res.render('pages/index', {pictures : results});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That indeed did the trick :) thanks so much! Just have to figure out how the navbar works properly. Now when I press on the home menu it gets the error again.

Comment: see the updated answer, this could solve the other errors

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the pictures in to render function

```
 return res.render('../views/pages/index', {pictures : results} );
```